# How to override Validation.xml from module-customer

Tags: magento2, customer, overrides, validation, rules

I want to override `vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/validation.xml`
This `validation.xml` in custom module.

Baically I want to change below file location with my custom module file

```
<rule name="check_name">
   <entity_constraints>
        <constraint alias="name_validator" class="Magento\Customer\Model\Validator\Name" />
   </entity_constraints>
</rule>
```

This `Magento\Customer\Model\Validator\Name` with `Vendor\Module\Model\Validator\Name`

If anyone have any idea please share.

TIA

Comment: You could try a rewrite or plugin. Also, have you tried creating a custom extension and adding in etc/validation.xml the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the whole class or use plugin to override the function only. I would prefer plugin.

1. To override the class, in your `etc/di.xml` add this:

   `<preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\Validator\Name" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Validator\Name" />`

Now your `Vendor\Module\Model\Validator\Name` class:

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Validator;
class Name extends \Magento\Customer\Model\Validator\Name
{
  //your code
}
```

More info: https://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/

2. For plugin method check this: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/plugins/

Comment: Plugin does not override the private function, And I want to override the private function. But can't achieve it with preference. So I want to override validation.xml to change the path

Comment: `<preference>` is for overriding the whole class. If you are overriding the private function then you will need to override the public function that calls the private function. :)